# Mysterious padding increase

Tags: javascript, css, padding

I'm learning and learning, currently creating a validation class. I have one little bug that I would ask you guys, what you think of it.

### tooltip part of Javascript

```
this.toolTip = function(){
var selector = $("#regForm #"+this.idName);
$(selector).focus(function(){
    tooltip = "<div class='tooltip'>"+tooltip+"</div>";
    $(selector).after(tooltip);
}); // focus

$(selector).blur(function(){
    $('.tooltip:parent').remove();
}); // blur
};
```

This is the tooltip function I wrote, basically what I expect it to do is showing the tooltip in that div, then delete not just the text, but the div, too. I think it's working perfectly, but the css don't say that.

### tooltip part of CSS

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

My experience is pretty poor in `CSS` yet, but I'm developing and I'm trying.

When I focus on an input again, it's padding increasing, when I click again, it increases again. Can you guys help me inspect the code? http://purpost.me/o/form

(as design, I tried to copy tipsy tooltip)

Here is a picture of the bug:
 [image: http://s30.postimg.org/sgfh9va3l/bug.jpg]

Thanks in advance! :)

#### UPDATE:

[image]

**Updated** jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThePianist/hExkP/3/

When I change the CSS .tooltip's padding to zero, the padding doesn't increase, but the div looking bad obviously. When I tried `<div class="tooltip"><span>'+tooltip+'</span></div>` and give the span the padding attribute, it started growing on focus again .. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! A friend of mine called my attention to this line:

#### JS before

```
tooltip = '<div class="tooltip '+selector.attr('id')+'T">'+tooltip+'</div>';
```

I call the class property `tooltip` as well, now I overwrote that with this line.

#### JS after

```
$(selector).focus(function(){
var tooltipHTML = '<div class="tooltip '+selector.attr('id')+'T">'+tooltip+'</div>';
selector.after(tooltipHTML);
}); // focus
```

"The problem is that you are using the variable `tooltip` for multiple things. The before code defining a variable called tooltip with html in it and it's used for text
`+tooltip+` part in JavaScript, you don't want to declare variables globally like this."

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is when clicking inside the form inputs there is some script appending more empty divs underneath `<div class="tooltip"><div>`. So when you click out and click back in, it is registering another instance of the click and appending again thus making the tooltip larger. Therefore, it would appear is a javascript error with the append/after section. If you pop your codes in a jsFiddle i can take a proper look at a solution for you :)

EDIT:

From looking at the code, it is the section:

```
$(selector).focus(function(){
    tooltip = "<div class='tooltip'>"+tooltip+"</div>";
    $(selector).after(tooltip);
}); // focus
```

That appears to be causing issues. Ideally it should check to see if the code added after already exists, and if it does, don't run the after function again

Comment: Here you go! :) Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/ThePianist/hExkP/2/ -- I'm sorry, I didn't use JSFiddle before, so I just dropped my code into it now.

Comment: No worries, i'll have a quick look

Comment: You put the css in the HTML section

Comment: Edited! There is the new link, sorry. :) jsfiddle.net/ThePianist/hExkP/2

Comment: Just wondering, any reason you're not doing this in jQuery? :P

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The jQuery validation library? As I said I'm not sure which library I'll be allowed to use and also as I'm learning now, it's a good practice, too. :)

Comment: Creating something like this would be a little easier with jQuery instead of raw JS. I know what your prob is just trying to work out a fix haha

Comment: Look at the code buddy! I wrote it using jQuery. What did I write that I could have done better?

Comment: Can you give me an example? :)

Comment: I'm happy to receive any advice if you think I'm approaching it from the wrong way. By the way, do you have any idea where my code gets buggy?

Comment: Sorry mate, very tired haha, so you have, my bad. Yeah it's literally the after() that's giving you these issues. Trying a few ideas but nothing is working as expected. Give me a little longer and i'll see what i can do.

Comment: Have updated my answer to show the bit that i *think* is the issue. I'm way too tired and its xmas now so going to go to bed. Let me know if you find a solution :)

Comment: No worries! It was 2 am here when I wrote this post, too. :) I went to sleep as well. Merry Christmas! I didn't find a solution yet, but I found out that it actually deletes the div, so I still don't know why it duplicates the padding.

Comment: Morning, merry christmas to you too :) You're right, it removes the parent class, that's correct. But if you inspect the element with firebug it actually leaves the div tags there and is literally ONLY removing the class, not the element. Divs constantly get appended and it is expanding it down. Thats def where the problem lies

Comment: Found the solution, below I posted it! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)